# Prove that $4k(k+1) =5^n - 1$ has infinitely many solutions in positive integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Similarly, I believe $k(k+1) = 3^n -1$ has only the trivial solution $k = 1, n = 1$

ps: Sorry, I mis-typed the equation. Well, the solution now is fairly trivial. So no need to prove the title equation.

Comment: So these are conjectures, or why do you believe these statements to be true?

Comment: I have proofs for both. I believe my proof for first equation is correct and second one most likely correct.

Comment: Then why are you asking?

Comment: Maybe your proof for the second is perfect.  Or maybe it's pure junk.  How the heck are we supposed to know if you don't tell us anything?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(2k+1)^2=4k(k+1)+1$. Substitute.

Answer (score 0):

$k(k+1) = 3^n - 1$.

If $n>1$, then $RHS \equiv -1$ (mod 9). But we have $k(k+1) \equiv 2$ (mod 9).

Comment: Seems like $k(k+1)$ can be any of $0, 2, 3, 6$ mod $9$. (Which, of course, still works for the proof.)

Comment: Similarly, for the $5^n-1$ equation, we can check by brute force that $k(k+1)$ can only be one of $\{0, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 15, 17, 20, 22\}$ mod $25$, which is a contradiction if $n>1$.

Comment: Well, we know that $k(k+1) \not\equiv 0$ (mod 3) so I only take $k \equiv 1$ (mod 3)

Comment: How does one solve this for any odd prime $p$ i.e, $k(k+1) = p^n -1$?. The n = even case may be easier...

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of the first equation, you are correct about both equations.

**First equation:** $4k(k+1) = 5^n - 1$.
Rewriting by completing the square (see Thomas Andrews' hint) gives
$$
(2k+1)^2 = 5^n
$$
which we can see has a solution whenever $n$ is even.

**Second equation:**
Consider it modulo $9$. For $n \ge 2$, $3^n - 1 \equiv 8 \pmod{9}$. On the other hand, $k(k+1)$ is either divisible by $3$, or $\equiv 2 \pmod{9}$.
So $n = 1$, and thus $k(k+1) = 2$, implying $k = 1$.